# Coding a text adventure game

Tags: python

I'm teaching myself Python, and to practice I decided that I would try to write a text adventure game.

This is what I have so far:

```
print("Darkness surrounds you.  You are likely to be eaten by a grue.")
move = input("Above you, you see some light breaking through the rock ceiling. ")

if move == "up":
    print("You climb out of the cave.  You are in a dense forest.")
    print("Below you is the hole in the ground you climbed out of.")
    print("To the north you see a footpath.")
    print("To the south and west there is a dense growth of trees and blackberry bushes.")
    move = input("To the east there is a wooden cabin. ")
else if move == "l"
    print("Darkness surrounds you.  You are likely to be eaten by a grue.")
else if move == "look"
    print("Darkness surrounds you.  You are likely to be eaten by a grue.")
else if move == "i":
    print("You are empty-handed.")
else if move == "inventory":
    print("You are empty-handed.")
elif move == "quit":
    print("Bah humbug! Quitters never win, and winners never quit.")
else:
    print("You have been eaten by a grue.")

if move == "pick blackberries"
    print("They are quite tasty.")
if move == "eat blackberries"
    print("They are quite tasty.")
if move == "take blackberries"
    print("You take a handful of blackberries")
if move == "take blackberry branch"
    print("You scrape yourself badly on the blackberry brambles.")
```

And so on.

I have a few questions:

1) How do I code the equivalent of "if move == this OR that"?  As in, "move == s or south".  I Googled "or python" but the results just talked about Boolean values.

2) How do I create "inventory"?  Should I use lists for that somehow?  I have some inkling of how to do it, but I haven't thought of it yet.

3) How do I make it so that if the player leaves the location, they can come back to it, without typing up the description all over again in the code?

4) How do I make it so that in every location in the game, the "else" is "I don't understand what you're saying" without typing that into the code after every "input" if then statement.

5) In general, how do I make it repeat things, so I don't have to write the code out for each location in the game?

6) Should I use modules for this?  If so, how do I go about finding the right modules?

I plan on adding some other things, such as .lower to make it not case sensitive.

I looked at some tutorials for making a text adventure game in Python, but they were for making simple short games, or they were in C# or something.

Thank you!!!

Comment: You are asking good questions, but the scope is too large for stackoverflow.  You could try posting to codereview stackexchange for some general feedback.  That should get you pointed in a good direction.

Comment: Ok, I guess it's not the right type of question.  Sorry about that.

Comment: Thank you for your help everyone!!!  I've been working on it, and the text adventure game is chugging along

Answer (score 1):

Wow, that is a lot of questions. Typically I would flag this post as too broad, but I will try to answer some of them here.

1. > How do I code the equivalent of "if move == this OR that"? As in, "move == s or south". I Googled "or python" but the results just talked about Boolean values.

Well, there are a few ways to do this. One way is to use the `in` operator in python and use a list of accepted values. That would look something like

```
movesNorth = ["north","North","N","n"]
movesSouth=["south","South","S","s"]
movesEast=["east","East","E","e"]
movesWest=["west","West","W","w"]
if(move in movesNorth):
    ...
elif(move in movesSouth):
    ...
```

Another way to do that would be to use the `or` keyword for each input. This is different in python from most languages, since other languages typically use the bitwise `or` and `and` operators (`||` and `|` and `&&` and `&` respectively). You may notice that there are two methods to perform OR and AND checks in other languages, and they function slightly differently. Its an interesting topic to read about for a beginner, and I would recommend it!
This would look something like this:

```
if(moves == "North" or moves == "n" or moves == "North" or moves == "N"):
    ...
```

2. > How do I create "inventory"? Should I use lists for that somehow? I have some inkling of how to do it, but I haven't thought of it yet.

This question is a bit broad and more of a personal preference. Personally I would create a player and inventory object/class. The player object would have an inventory as an attribute, and the inventory class would probably use a list or map of some kind to store the information of what it contains. I would say this question would be best answered by you trying to implement something, and then posting a new question when you get stuck.

3. > How do I make it so that if the player leaves the location, they can come back to it, without typing up the description all over again in the code?

Perhaps keeping track of the locations the player visits inside of a list, and then if the current location already exists in this list of visited items, you know you don't need to display the text. This would require a 2d array (a list of lists) to keep track of x and y coordinates across a grid. `Moves=[[]]` You would then access the square at (0,1) with the index `moves[0][1].` This gets the 0th row, then accesses the element inside the 1st column.

4. > How do I make it so that in every location in the game, the "else" is "I don't understand what you're saying" without typing that into the code after every "input" if then statement.

I would define a function for getting player movement that handles the input validation before moving the player. Once again I would use the `in` keyword with list functionality, but I would add all the acceptable inputs into one list.

```
def getInput():
    acceptedInputs = ["n","s","e","w","inv","etc..."]
    userInput = "NULL"
    while(userInput not in acceptedInputs):
        userInput = input("Whatever text you want displayed asking for input: ")
    return userInput
```

5. > In general, how do I make it repeat things, so I don't have to write the code out for each location in the game?

This is the exact reason why functions were invented! A good idea to keep in mind is if you are repeatedly copying and pasting the same code throughout your whole program, you should just turn it into a function. This is what the `def` keyword does, and you should definitely research and play around with functions as they will be very useful to you in the future. Perhaps start with defining a function that takes two int arguments and adding them together.

6. > Should I use modules for this? If so, how do I go about finding the right modules?

This would all depend on what you are trying to accomplish. You could use modules for this, but since you are still learning it would probably be easier to understand what is going in by not doing that. When you move onto a language like C or C++ (where you have a header file and then a class file) this module will be implicitly easy to understand. 6 in one hand, half dozen in the other in my opinion. I would definitely recommend the use of functions over separating it out into modules.

**Welcome**

Also, welcome to Stack Overflow! Try not to post a flurry of questions at once in the future, but limit yourself to one (or maybe two) questions in a post at a time. Typically this site is more useful for things such as "I have this code, I thought it would do X, but it is doing y. How do I make it do X or why is it doing y?" questions.

If this post satisfies your questions, then by all means don't forget to click that checkmark under the vote down option! If you have any ambiguities on what I wrote, feel free to comment. I am on SO Monday-Friday up until 5:00 PM EST, but outside of those times you probably will have to wait for a response.

Answer (score 0):

You need to study data structures.  Even a simple text adventure game needs highly organized data.

An inventory of items can be held on a list, which is a basic data structure in most higher-level computer languages.  Python has lists.

A data structure that holds a map is more complicated.  Each location on the map needs, at a minimum, a list of its neighbors and the directions one would take to each each neighbor.  When you have matched pairs of objects, like a list of directions and a list of neighbors, a "mapping" data structure is usually a convenient way to organize that information.  In Python, the mapping data structure is called a dictionary.

You look up items on lists and in dictionaries by using index values.  For a list, the index values are integers, starting at zero.  For a dictionary, the index values are also called "keys" and they don't have to be integers starting at zero.    You can use strings as dictionary keys.

So let's say you're walking on a cliff edge at location 25.  If you move north, you get to location 30.  If you move south, you go to location 22.  You can't move east or west (well, you could, but in one of those directions you fall off the cliff, and I'll leave it to you as to whether you want to allow suicidal moves in your game).  So your movement dictionary for location 25 in Python could read as follows: {"north" : 30, "south" : 22}.  If the user tries to move east or west, there is no defined result, so your code will have to handle that situation.  You might have more direction options, such as "up" or "down".  It probably isn't possible to move in every direction from every location, and dictionaries handle the variability well.

Language processing is another fun and complicated area.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use:

   ```
   if move in ['i', 'inventory']
   ```
2. If your inventory is a simple list of words, it would be simpler to maintain a normal list.
3. You could use functions to try and not repeat your code.
4. Since you are a beginner, I would suggest that you add the else statement every time. However you can use a decorator(slightly advanced concept) where you can check that 'if move not in acceptable_moves: print("error")'.
5. For this, you need to understand how graphs work, or for a smaller game you can try to use dictionaries. Where the key would be the place and the value would be a dictionary again. For example:

   ```
   {"cave": {"up":"dense_forest"}, 
    "dense_forest": {"north": "footpath"}}
   ```

   In this way, you could pass the location to a function and print statements accordingly. The value of your inner dictionary (eg. footpath) would be a key of your main dictionary.
6. You need not use any external modules as of now. Try experimenting with what you know!